# Generate a symmetric key on iOS using Security.framework

Tags: ios, encryption, encryption-symmetric, security-framework

I'm struggling to generate a symmetric key in iOS using the security framework. There is a method `SecKeyGenerateSymmetric()` in `SecKey.h` but its for macOS only. The only thing I see available is `SecKeyGeneratePair()` which is for asymmetric encryption.

Also from reading this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/using_keys_for_encryption) it looks the only way to do symmetric encryption is by generating an asymmetric key pair and calling `SecKeyCreateEncryptedData()` with the public key and behind the scenes a symmetric key is generated but you don't have access to it. I need to have access to the symmetric key.

If anyone has experience doing symmetric encryption on iOS I would be grateful of some guidance.

Comment: Take a look at CryptoSwift https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift

Answer (score 0):

With CryptoKit's introduction this can be done using the following code:

```
 import CryptoKit

 //generate Symmetric  key
 let key = SymmetricKey(size: .bits256)
```

Here is an example using AES-GCM method for encrypting and decrypting using the 32 byte symmetric key:

```
//generate Symmetric  key
 let key = SymmetricKey(size: .bits256)

  //encrypt plaintext
   let encryptedData = try!  AES.GCM.seal("plain-text".data(using: .utf8)!, using: key)
    print("Encrypted data using symmetric key:\(encryptedData)")
    
    //decrypt data
    let sealedBoxRestored = try! AES.GCM.SealedBox(nonce: encryptedData.nonce, ciphertext: encryptedData.ciphertext, tag: encryptedData.tag)
    let decryptedData = try! AES.GCM.open(sealedBoxRestored, using: key)
    print("Decrypted:\n\(String(data: decryptedData, encoding: .utf8)!)")
```